# Correlation between different types of variables( categorical/numerical) and a binary categorical one output

Tags: correlation, feature-selection

i am doing research and in my articles i found that Pearson correlation can be applied between numerical variables and an output label variable.

in my case i have 72 variables (20 are numerical (float) and the rest are categorical non ordinal and i codified them to (0,1,2,...n)).My target output is a 0/1 result which represents category.

My question here Pearson correlation is it a good way to calculate the correlation between variables???

or i need to split my data based on type and then apply the appropriate correlation measurement like Chi sqaure for categorical/ categorical variable, Pearson corraltion between the numerical/numerical and anova between categorical/numerical variable

Thanks for explanation

Answer (score -1):

**Correlation as a dependency measure is effective only when the data is multivariate normal.**

Multivariate normality also implies that individual marginal distributions are also normal.

Say, your data has a categorical independent variable with only two/three levels - Yes/No or Good/Bad/Worse. Clearly, with only two/three data points for this particular categorical variable, we cannot say it is marginally normal. Hence, the data might not be multi-variate normal. So, in your case, correlation may not be a good measure of dependency.

Even among the numerical variables, first check if they are individually (marginally) normal-ly distributed or not. If yes, then you can use correlation. Else go for the other metrics like Spearman's rho, etc.

Comment: This is very misleading. As a counter-example, suppose x is uniform, y = a + bx, and so y is uniform too, and correlation is 1. Are you saying that this is invalid because neither marginal distribution is normal? Correlation measures linearity of relationship and the marginal distribution of either variable is secondary. At worst, detailed inference may be a bit iffy without normality but we have had permutation tests and bootstrapping for over 40 years as alternatives.  (The correlation between binary variables is also well defined, so categorical variables aren't all out of the question.)